# When i change NLS ora gives "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error

Tags: oracle, nls-lang, nls-sort, nls-comp

My Oracle NLS parameters is:

```
NLS_SORT = TURKISH
NLS_COMP= BINARY

COLUMNA1=VARCHAR2
```

query:

```
  SELECT COLUMNA1,
  (SELECT TABLEB.COLUMB1 FROM TABLEB WHERE TABLEB.COLUMNB2 = TABLEA.COLUMNA1)
  FROM TABLEA GROUP BY TABLEA.COLUMNA1
```

This query worked and return data.

But when i change

```
NLS_SORT = TURKISH_AI
NLS_COMP= LINGUISTIC
```

This query points `"= TABLEA.COLUMNA1"`  and gives *"ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"* error?

In my project, i have a lot of query like this, and i couldnt change all.
And if my query wrong, why run before?

Thanks in advance!